# For finite group $G$ of order $n$ such that there exists a unique subgroup of order equal to each positive divisor of $n$. Is it necessarily cyclic?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be a finite group of order $n$. Suppose $k$ is a positive integer such that $k|n$, then there exists a unique subgroup of order $k$.

Is it necessarily cyclic?

If $G$ is Abelian, then I can prove it, but if $G$ is nonAbelian, then it is difficult to me to prove or disprove.

Comment: If G is the non-cyclic group of order 4 then it has a unique subgroup of order 4 (namely G itself) and this subgroup is non-cyclic.

Comment: I guess, you meant, there exists a unique subgroup of order $k$ *for each* $k|n$, else, of course every finite group of order $n$ has exactly one subgroup of order $n$.

Comment: Yes @Berci, I meant that.